# WebAPI RC 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib,

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an webapi application running .net4 that I am trying to get working on a server. The api works fine locally.

> Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

What do I need to change to get this to work on my server?

Comment: Isn't this new in 4.5? If so, install 4.5 on the server.

Comment: The app is only running with .net4. If I can get away without needing to install 4.5 on the server I would rather not have to install it

Comment: This type has existed since .NET 3.5 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute(v=vs.90).aspx) so framework version is likely not the problem (unless you don't actually have .NET 4 installed on the server). Are you getting a stack trace along with that exception?

Comment: We have had scattered reports of this but have been unable to get a live repro.  If you can email *both* the project *and* the binary resulting from compilation to us, we would really appreciate it.  My email address is levib@microsoft.com.

Comment: Thanks Levi, I ended up installing the .net4.5 framework over the top of .net and it sorted my problem

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure you were compiling against .NET 4 and not .NET 4.5?  We moved ExtensionAttribute to mscorlib in .NET 4.5 (so we could put extension methods in mscorlib).  I'd expect to see an error like that if you compiled something against .NET 4.5 and tried to run it on .NET 4.

EDIT: Actually, if you are using ILMerge, you need to use the path to the .NET 4.0 reference assemblies in the targetplatform switch, instead of the path to the implementation, as described in this blog post: http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2012/02/29/What-you-should-know-about-running-ILMerge-on-Net-45-Beta-assemblies-targeting-Net-40.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution (others with same exception) could be that your build server has not have the .net 4.0 reference assemblies, after installing .net 4.5 you'll need to copy them from your dev box.

These are typically somewhere like:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

For more details see [Marc's blog post](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.nz/2012/09/iterator-blocks-missing-methods-and-net.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also check the DLLs your project is dependent on.  I was having the same problem and found that a single DLL was causing the issue.  This DLL was an older version (compiled for .NET 4.0) on my local machine where the site ran fine through the localhost, but was a newer version (compiled for .NET 4.5) on the live server where the site failed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed by creating a new application pool for my site after installing .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Or just: aspnet_regiis -i in an admin-console after the update of the framework on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I have little experience with .NET and I had the same problem with `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute`.

**The solution:** Remove the project references, the reference to Framework 4.5, because in my case since I had not installed this Framework.