# Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note > that attribute names are case-sensitive

Tags: asp.net, publish

I try to publish a web application from my VS2012 to a remote computer.
I published the files but when I try to open the website, I get this error:

> **Configuration Error**
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note
>   that attribute names are case-sensitive.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 41: 
Line 42:     <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
Line 43:     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" />
Line 44:     <authentication mode="Forms">   
Line 45:       <forms loginUrl="~/" timeout="2880" />
```

**(line 43 is in red )**

On the remote computer :
* IIS7 is installed (and also IIS6, I think)
* ASP.NET 4.0 is installed
* "aspnet_regiis -ir" > installed successfully
* IIS7 > Application Pools > ASP.NET 4.0 > poining to ".NET Framework v4.0.30319"
* IIS7 >  my web application > "ASP.NET 4.0" (Integrated) is chosen.
I don't know if it 's important but server's windows is Widows Server 2008 RT Enterprise 64-bit and my computer is windows 7 32-bit.

Nothing helped...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure 4.0 is chosen?  I got that error when the web site was setup to use ASP.NET 2.0...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the selected app pool for your application? The error you're getting really does mean that ASP.NET 2.0 is trying run your application. See [this canonical post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen)

Comment: I edited the question and added 2 screenshots...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`httpRuntime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx) did not have `targetFramework` available for set, remove it and it will work.

Comment: I get a different error - "Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. "

Comment: @TamarG This is your real error, remove it and solve the next error.

Comment: @TamarG for the next error look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896894/webapi-rc-system-runtime-compilerservices-extensionattribute-from-assembly-ms

Comment: I installed .net 4.5 on the target server and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar issue when I try to publish the website.

The code compiled fine in both Debug and Release but got **Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'...** while publishing the site after updating my solution to **.net 4.7.2** from older version **.net3.5**

I then updated my **.pubxml** file to contain

```
**<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>**

<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
```

It worked for me then